# Play console won't work inside project directory

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I wanted to take a look to the play! Java Frameworkd. Therefore, I have downloaded the framework saved it to my home directory and created a new app with the console with
`play new hello-world`
But if I cd into the dir and call play in the shell I always get the message:

> .../play/play-2.1.0/framework/build: Permission denied

I use Ubuntu 12.04 if this matters... . Has anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file is just a simple shell script. You don't seem to have the proper permissions to execute it. I'm not sure how that happened, but you should be able to fix it with a simple `chmod`:

```
$> chmod +rx /path/to/playframework/framework/build
```

Of course, you need to replace `/path/to/playframework` with the path where your Play is installed.